# Cannot connect to sqlexpress

Tags: sql-server-express, ssms

I just installed of  SQL Server Management Studio Express 2012, and then I try to connect database engine with servername : ./sqlexpress, but it failed.

Its raised message like below :

### TITLE: Connect to Database Engine

Cannot connect to ./sqlexpress.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3&LinkId=20476

---

The system cannot find the path specified.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Could this be just the wrong slash character? why not use `.\SQLEXPRESS`?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this in the past, most likely the wrong instance name or address. Since it is a local DB instance on your machine you will want to try connecting to **(local)\SQLEXPRESS** *[This is the default SQL Express Instance]*

Comment: It should be (local)\SQLEXPRESS. Sounds stupid but it will fail to connect if the slash is the wrong way around!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a local instance of SQL Server you can just use localhost as the server name.  Also you can try to remove the ./ before the server name.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else gets a failed to connect to server instance while trying to connect to a DB in C#, make sure you add localhost to the front of your database server address if you're on the same machine.

ie: myDatabase2012
should be put in as localhost\\myDatabase2012 (the second \ is needed to escape the first)